# same query gives different results (nodejs, postgres, date)

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a problem with postgresql and nodejs.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
        COUNT(user_id),
        DATE(signed_up) AS date
FROM
        users
GROUP BY
        DATE(signed_up)
```

This is a simple query but I'm not getting the correct results.

When I use the query tool in pgadmin to execute this query, I get the correct format:

```
+--------+-------------------+
| count  | date              |
+--------+-------------------+
+ 2      | 2020-01-01        |
+--------+-------------------+
```

When I do the exact same query in node.js (using [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/)), I get the following output.

```
+--------+------------------------------+
| count  | date                         |
+--------+------------------------------+
+ 2      | 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z         |
+--------+------------------------------+
```

The signed_up field is a TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE field.

What could possibly be wrong?

**EDIT**:

I have an array of dates in the following format:

```
let array = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', ...]
```

I loop over the results of the query with

```
let index
dates.forEach(item => {
    index = result.rows.findIndex(e => e.date === item)
    // because the array is in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD' and the 
    // results are in the format 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ', there is no match, 
    // so every index will be -1.
})
```

I'm trying to check if dates, defined in an array, exists in the results of a query. That's what I'm trying to do.

**SOLUTION:**

CAST(DATE(signed_up) AS varchar) worked for me.

Comment: What makes you think anything is wrong? They're just displaying the same point in time in slightly different ways.

Comment: yes but I need it in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD', because I do something with it further in the code. How can I convert it? Is it possible with SQL or should I use a javascript library like moment or so?

Comment: Could you give a [mre] of the *problem* you're having? What is preventing you from using that date, or formatting it however you want?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Do you actually have a *string* from the database, or a *date*? Did you try getting the specific part you wanted as a string?

Comment: when I do CAST(signed_up AS date) I get the same results. I get a date from the database, not a string (when I do a console.log of the results).

Comment: Oh yeah, I think I figured out my problem: I'm comparing a date object with a string, isn't it? How can I convert/cast the date object from the results to a string?

Comment: So why *would* `e.date === item`, given that one's a date and one's a string? This is nothing to do with the format you're seeing displayed in different DB clients, you need to **create the appropriate string** for comparison. I would recommend research on that topic, there are plenty of questions on formatting a Date to a string already.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your help, @johnrsharpe